# Joomla folder listing problem

Tags: php, joomla

I'm working on a Joomla component which involves files manipulation. For this purpose, I tried to list all folders in the "images" folder (which consists all of images used in the website). So here's my simple code to test this:

```
<?php
   foreach (JFolder::folders('images') as $folder){
        echo $folder."\n";
   }
 ?>
```

However, it returns an empty array. This is not the case if I use JFolder::files; it will list all files in the said folder. So is there any way for me to retrieve the folders list? Or is there something wrong with the system etc etc?

As usual, let me know if I have to add anything as clarification. Thanks for your help!

SOLVED: Instead of JFolder::folders('images'), I changed it to JFolder::folders(JPATH_ROOT.'/images'). Maybe it's missing the actual path to the folder.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're after:

```
$tree = JFolder::listFolderTree('images');
```

See reference here: http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/FileSystem/JFolder.html#listFolderTree

Failing that I would suggest checking the permissions of your directories are that of your files.

Comment: I tried listFolderTree too but still returns empty array. I've checked the file permission in System Info section but it says the "images" directory is writable, so it shouldn't be a problem. Any other workaround?

Comment: That's good that it's "writable" but to just humour me could you check that the directories inside your "images" directory have the same permissions as the files?

NB: It isn't normal to have your permissions setup this way (files and folders the same), but for testing it should be fine.

Comment: So I finally found the workaround. Instead of JFolder::folders('images'), I changed it to JFolder::folders(JPATH_ROOT.'/images'), which works perfectly. I think I'm just missing the actual path to the folder. Nevertheless thanks for your help, and you deserve a voteup!